# What permissions are needed to Create Groups and Add users to Groups?

Tags: permissions, office-365, groups, provider-hosted-app

I am currently developing a **SharePoint Provider-hosted-Add-In** which should be run on O365.

I added **FullControl** to the SiteCollection and Web and everything worked fine. FullControl is not allowed, though.

So I tried **Managed** instead of **FullControl**, but that gave me an access denied when creating the Groups.

So my questions are:

- What are the **minimum requirements** to create groups in O365?
- Are there **other (less) permissions** needed to add users to an existing group?
- As the groups only have to be created after installation:  Can the app have low permissions but use the Administrators level to create those groups?

I already tried `SharePointContextProvider.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()` but **still got an access denied**, even though the user can create groups manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answers of your questions:

1. You will need **FullControl** permission to create group.
2. No. You can take reference from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219576%28office.15%29.aspx).
3. No.  SharePoint uses an App Only context it really doesn’t matter what rights the end user has on the content – all that matters is what rights have been granted to the App. Because the App can effectively run with **elevated privileges** (i.e. more rights than the user might have), it requires you to be a Site Collection Administrator to install. App Only permissions don’t use the permissions of the current user, it just uses the App permissions.

**References:**

- https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/security-in-sharepoint-apps-part-6/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx